# Problem getting reference (bibliography) page to show up

Tags: bibliographies

When I compile on sharelatex online my ref page shows up, with the in text citations. When I switch over to texshop on my mac either nothing at all shows up, or the exact content of my bib file shows up with no reference heading or numbering. The in text citations show up as [?] and i get " Citation `History' on page 6 undefined on input line 71 
" my document structure is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\input{./title.tex}
\table of contents
\section{section1}
\section{section2}
\pagebreak
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

and bib file looks like this:

```
@article{History,
title={Title},
author={author},
url={url},
year={year},
publisher={publisher}
}
```

I've compiled it dozens of times in working through a few other issues, all the while the bibliography has been at the bottom of the tex document.

I have tried the `\nocite{History}` command but it does nothing.

I have double, triple, and quadruple checked for typos and have found none. 
any suggestions?

Comment: you need to run bibtex to generate the bibliography and then latex again to include it

Comment: I assume that the problem is as described here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.